# Can I Find ALL Connection 1-Forms from the Gauge Group?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, gauge-theory

I would like to know if its possible that given a principal fiber bundle $(P, \pi, M, G)$, the gauge group $GA(P)$ of all gauge transformations $f:P\to P$, and a single connection $1$-form $\omega_0 \in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ if I am able to obtain the whole space of connection $1$-forms by considering all $1$-forms of the type $f^*\omega_0$ for $f \in GA(P)$.  I've been reading [Bleecker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486445461) and [Hamilton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319684388) for a research project I'm doing, and maybe I've missed it but I'm not entirely certain this claim was ever proven, disproven, or mentioned in these texts.  If $\mathcal{C}$ is the space of connection one forms then we can consider the mapping $\mathcal{C} \times GA(P) \to \mathcal{C}$ given by  $(\omega, f) \to f^*\omega$ to be a right action.  I suppose my question is equivalent to asking whether or not this action is ever transitive, and if so under what circumstances.  Either way, since I'm working on a variational problem I may not need to know the full space of connections but simply how to update locally.

I'm willing to make some hefty assumptions here:

- I'm fine if $M$ is connected and simply connected,
- $P$ can be a trivial bundle

Comment: You should write the gauge transformation explicitly in terms of the action of $G$, and then see how this transforms the connection $1$-form.

Comment: In general it's not, even if $M$ is simply connected. The natural object of study would be the ''Module Space'' $\mathcal{M} := \mathcal{C}(P)/\mathcal{G}$ 
i.e. the space of connections modulo the space of gauge transformations. This can be a manifold of dimension $n > 0$. This might be overkill for what you want, but I didn't have the time to investigate the case at hand... 
This goes back to the work of S. Donaldson, and chapter 17 of the book 
''Index Theory with Applications to Mathematics and Physics'' by 
 D. Bleecker and B. Booss-Bavnbek might help you.